# Как исключить файл из VCS в PyCharm или других продуктах JetBrains?

Tags: контроль-версий, pycharm, jetbrains

В проект под VCS (допустим - Git) добавлен файл (в дереве проекта отображается зеленым), коммит еще не произведен. Вопрос: как исключить файл из VCS (чтобы он отобразился красным) не удаляя с диска?

Единственное решение, которое я нашел, это скопировать этот файл внешними средствами на уровень выше проекта, удалить его в проекте средствами самой IDE (иначе она запоминает принадлежность файла VCS даже в отсутствии самого файла) и вернуть файл обратно опять внешними средствами, только тогда он высвечивается красным. Но это - абсурд, должен быть штатный способ для этого. Если существует операция "Add to VCS", то должна существовать и обратная ей. Тем более, что это никак не затрагивает саму VCS, если этот файл еще не разу не был закоммичен.

Непосредственно сейчас столкнулся с этой проблемой в PyCharm, но, видимо, эта проблема общая для всех продуктов JetBrains.

Comment: Revert должен просто снять наблюдение за файлом и снова пометить его красным. Но проверьте на всякий случай на тестовом файле.

Comment: Разве .gitignore не помогает в этом?

Comment: @Etki: Действительно работает! Никогда бы не подумал. Получается, что Revert имеет два разных поведения в зависимости от того вызывается он на закоммеченом или на новом файле. В первом случае происходит откат изменений, но статус файла не меняется, во втором случае меняется статус, но не меняется содержимое.

Напишите ваш комментарий в ответ, кажется, это и есть решение.

Comment: @titov-andrei, если файл УЖЕ добавлен в репозиторий, добавление его в  .gitignore ничем не поможет.

Comment: сначала надо удалить из репозитария, потом игнор, а вообще лучше пользуйтесь отдельным клиентом: TortoiseGit, Gittyup и т. п.

Answer (score 2):

конечно же в JetBrains существует функция, которая удаляет файл из системы контроля версий. Эта функция называется Revert.
Вы можете вызвать её двумя способами:
а) Выделите файлы, которые вы не хотите коммитить и нажмите Ctrl+Alt+Z . Они "покраснеют", как вы и хотите.
б) Нажмите правой кнопкой мыши на нужном файле. Затем откройте меню Git и нажмите Revert.

Comment: Сейчас при нажатии Ctrl+Alt+Z срабатывает Rollback и при этом он откатывает изменения и файл продолжает отслеживаться, как сейчас можно убрать файл из отслеживания?

Answer (score 0):

> Сейчас при нажатии Ctrl+Alt+Z срабатывает Rollback и при этом он
> откатывает изменения и файл продолжает отслеживаться, как сейчас можно
> убрать файл из отслеживания?

Судя по всему rollback - это тот же revert. Вроде работает...

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]